# Error-checking for permissions and size when reading/writing files

Tags: android, io, filesystems, android-permissions, android-file

In Android, if I want to copy a file from one place to another:

1. How do I check that I have the correct Manifest permissions? I know you include the permissions in the manifest, but let's say we don't know that we included it or not -- how do we catch the exception if we lack the permission?
2. How can I verify that I have read access for the source file?
3. How can I verify that I have write access for the destination?
4. How can I verify that there is enough room to perform the write?
5. How can I verify that the write was performed successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do we catch the exception if we lack the permission?

That varies by permission.

> How can I verify that I have read access for the source file?

[Call `canRead()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#canRead%28%29) on the `File`.

> How can I verify that I have write access for the destination?

[Call `canWrite()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#canWrite()) on the `File`.

> How can I verify that there is enough room to perform the write?

You can't, insofar as by the time you have made the calculation, the value may have changed due to the behavior of other apps on the device.

You can use [methods on `StatFs`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html) to determine the available space, but I would give yourself a significant buffer.

> How can I verify that the write was performed successfully?

Start by calling `getFD().sync()` on your `FileOutputStream`, after `flush()` and before `close()`, to ensure all bytes are written to disk and are not being cached by the kernel and filesystem implementations. For most cases, that's sufficient.

You are also welcome to read the content back in and verify it against whatever you have in memory, to confirm that the file appears to contain what it should.

Comment: I don't understand the canWrite() example. Does copying/moving a file require write access? I was referring more to checking if I have the ability to write to the source medium but this probably ties into (1).

Comment: @KaliMa: "Does copying/moving a file require write access?" -- you need to able to write to the destination `File` for a copy. For a rename/move, you need to be able to read and write both the original location and the destination.

Comment: "That varies by permission." In what sense? I'm referring to things like (for example) android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: @KaliMa: "In what sense?" -- where and how exceptions are thrown due to missing `READ_CONTACTS` will be substantially different than for `CAMERA`, or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, etc. "I'm referring to things like (for example) android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE " -- IIRC those will throw `SecurityExceptions` on affected disk I/O.

Comment: "you need to able to write to the destination File for a copy" That's what I mean: if I am trying to move a file to a new location, the file does not yet exist in that location

Comment: @KaliMa: So? You need a `File` object pointing to where you want the file to go. Call `canWrite()` on that `File` object. That is standard Java file I/O, nothing unique to Android.

Comment: I ask because if I do File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "testfile.txt"); and then output file.canWrite(); it returns false even though it's internal storage

Comment: @KaliMa: Ah, OK. For not-yet-existent files, I think you need to check write access on the parent directory (in this case, `getFilesDir()`). My apologies for not thinking that through. BTW, you can get rid of `+ ""`.

Comment: That is part of my question, though (checking write access of the directory). I was probably unclear: When I asked "How can I verify that I have write access for the destination?" I refer to the directory, not a file already in the directory.

Comment: @KaliMa: You should be able to call `canWrite()` on a `File` object pointing to the directory (e.g., `getFilesDir().canWrite()`).

Comment: Seems like I did need the "" for some reason: `File file = new File(this.getFilesDir() + "");` and `file.canWrite();` returns true, but `File file = new File(this.getFilesDir());` doesn't even compile. Apparently the constructor doesn't exist for a single file object input unless a filename is provided?

Comment: @KaliMa: `getFilesDir()` is a `File`. There is no `File(File)` constructor. In your previous example, you were calling `File(String, String)`, and that is not necessary, as there is a `File(File, String)` constructor.

Comment: I see now at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html -- I wonder why they don't have a File(File) constructor. At any rate this discussion has been helpful. Thank you!